# What is the right pronunciation of "planned"?

Tags: pronunciation, spoken-english

Today in my English class my teacher taught us about the "plan" verb using it in present perfect.

I was curious what is the right pronunciation of "planned" in American or British accent because as far as I have read in other books and sources, the "ed" sound in this word is pronunciated as /d/.

I also use applications like Elsa Speak which I think is good to improve the pronunciation and when I try the word "planned" I pronunciate it as "plant" and I got a score of 90% but my teachers pronunciation of "ed" in "planned" sounds like /z/.

Are "planned" and "plant" pronunciated same way?

I also checked them in dictionary.cambridge.org which as far as I know it is the "ultimate" or "official" way to pronunciate the words and the phonemes for these words are different. I wonder if "you can pronunciate planned as plant and people will understand you in most of cases" applies in this case?

Comment: I can't think of any variety of English that pronounces "planned" as "plant". I'm not saying there isn't one, but certainly no standard variety accepts that.

Comment: It's pretty standard to pronounce "ed" as /d/ after voiced consonants like /m/ /n/ /z/ /g/

Comment: In *my* BrE (South-East), ***plant*** rhymes with ***aren't, aunt, can't***, but ***planned*** rhymes with ***band, canned, stand***. Completely different vowel sounds, quite apart from the final consonant.

Comment: @gotube - I've listened to audiobooks where the American reader says 'second' in a way that sounds like 'secont' to my British ears. More than one, mostly from Audible. Not all readers do this; I think it might be a regional thing, although those who do it do not have heavy US regional accents.

Comment: What is your native language.  There is a common confusion caused when the sound symbolized by "d" or "t" in English is different to the ones symbolized by the same letters in your language.  Notably the pinyin "d" and "t" differ in aspiration not in voicing.  Whereas English "d" and "t" differ in voice, not in aspiration.

Comment: [pronounce is the verb] plan and plant (infinitives)/ planned and planted (simple past}. Please fix your question.

Comment: planned and planted would each be said the same [EXCEPT *maybe* for the a sound]. the ed sound versus the t sound is the SAME in both: talk, talked, [t]//and so is the ED sound in planned.,

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: That's the way we (at least some of us) pronounce *second* — with a /t/. It does not rhyme with *reckoned*, which has a /d/. It's an exceptional word, and I can't think of any other cases where we pronounce 'nd' as /nt/.

Comment: Could you please **fix your question**? The verb is pronounce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plant is pronounced with a final /t/ (unvoiced), and planned is pronounced with a /d/ (voiced). In addition, in British English the middle vowel is pronounced differently.

Under no circumstances is -ed pronounced /z/. You can find out more about how -ed is pronounced in different situations [here](https://www.englishclub.com/pronunciation/-ed.php).

Note that a final /d/ may sound more like a /t/ to some non-native speakers, and this may also affect their ability to reproduce the sound correctly.

---

In any language, a particular phoneme may be produced differently depending on the context- what phonemes precede or follow it- and production rules vary between languages. In [German](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final-obstruent_devoicing), a final voiced consonant becomes unvoiced, in [French](https://www.thoughtco.com/french-silent-letters-and-pronunciation-4078906) many final consonants are dropped completely, and in [Italian](https://www.thinkinitalian.com/why-does-almost-every-italian-word-end-with-a-vowel/) final consonants are uncommon.

Your perception of a phoneme, and your ability to reproduce it, may be affected by differences between the production rules of your own language and those of the language that you are learning.

There are several cues to distinguish voiced and unvoiced consonants. The main ones are:

- the strength of the release
- pre-voicing: whether the vocal cords are active before the release
- post-voicing: whether the vocal cords are active after the release.

In English, for a voiced consonant, pre-voicing usually only occurs after a vowel or voiced consonant, and post-voicing usually only occurs when followed by a vowel. The only reliable cue is that the release is stronger in unvoiced consonants.  The absence of post-voicing after a final consonant may make a final /d/ sound more like a /t/ to non-native speakers: as a result, they may reproduce it as a /t/.

Comment: All this is very true and something beginners need to learn. But it also must be said that the ed in planned is the same in any English. I would not even mention German, who cares? Why not make a list that is easily readable with examples?

Comment: How does this answer the OP's question? You don't mention the word "planned". I don't think the OP is asking for the rules of "-ed" pronunciation, but whether "planned" has a pronunciation exception

Comment: @Lambie You are looking at this from the perspective of a native english speaker.  I English Language Learners use different pronunciation rules, and Final Obstruent Devoicing may be an issue that makes them (and possibly the OP), say planned as plant.  German is a good example. If they understand *why* they mis-pronounce it, it's easier to correct.

Comment: @gotube I have added an answer to the specific question. The remaining text still needs to be said, because it explains two common issues for English Language Learners when pronouncing -ed.

Comment: OK. I've removed my dv. Why do you say the last sound of "planned" is "something between /t/ and /d/"? Isn't it just plain /d/?

Comment: @gotube Talking to native English speakers about final consonant voicing is like asking a fish what it's like living in water: the fish has never known anything else. Most English speakers interpret a gentle final d as a "plain /d/'. If you use a spectrogram analyser, it's relatively easy to see that there is a generally less voicing after a final consonant when compared to an initial consonant- as you would expect, because there is no vowel following it. Non-native English speakers may be able to pick up the difference if the phoneme rules for their language are sufficiently different.

Comment: I am looking at this as a former English teacher (10 years). And sounding out the words like planned and planted. They need to  hear it not understand a linguistic explanation fit for grad students.

Comment: @JavaLatte Interesting. Does that apply to all word-final /d/ sounds or just when it's the "-ed" morpheme?

Comment: @Gotube It probably applies to all voiced final consonants, and also to voiced consonants that are followed by a consonant: consider the strength of the b in abort and abdicate.

Comment: @lambie yes, they need to listen, but they need specific guidance what to listen for. I've provided a suitable hint for learners in the first paragraph. The rest is more aimed at native English speakers who don't seem able to look at this from a non-native's point of view.

Answer (score 2):

The word "plant" ends with a  [t]. The word planned ends with a [d].  So they don't sound the same.

There are three different sounds to learn: First [t<sup>h</sup>],  this is the sound of "t" at the start of words like "top". It is "aspirated" and pronounced with a little puff of air.  There is the unaspirated [t]. This sound is made when "t" isn't at the start.  For example in "stop".  And finally, there is the sound [d] that is made in, for example, "dog".  The [d] sound is voiced, but unaspirated.

Native English speakers are generally unaware of the difference between [t<sup>h</sup>] and [t].  They sound the same to us.  In other languages these are different.  In some languages the aspirated  [t<sup>h</sup>] is written in Latin script as "t" and the unaspirated [t] is written as "d".

Native English speakers are generally aware of the difference between [d] and [t], especially when these consonants are not at the start of a word.

You might be able to "get away with it", in context, as the grammatical roles of "plant" and "planned" are very different, and people might not notice the mistake - it will just be part of your accent.

The final consonant is never a fricative /z/ or /s/.

Comment: in the word planned, the end bit is exactly the same. The only difference and it can be minor at that is the a sound. deplaned/planned shows the contrast. Why get into British and American English for this particular term? Only the a might be different.

Comment: "deplaned"  I don't recognize that word, what does it mean? How is it pronounced?

Comment: It means to disembark from an aircraft, it's formed using the word plane. It is pronounced as you might expect, like plane.

Comment: is that relevant to the similarity or otherwise in the pronunciation of "planned" and "plant"?   Deplaned would (I suppose) have an /ei/ vowel sound, but the "ed" would be /d/ just as in planned, but different to plant.

Comment: I guess all three would be relevant: plan, plant and deplane. I thought the issue was something else. She mixes up tenses in her question. The accent thing is really a red herring.

Comment: I think your answer is too complicated for this OP. I think you need to spell out the t versus ed sound with examples and not use too many heavy linguistic terms. Also, the pond difference is not relevant to those past tenses. It's only for the sound of the a, in some cases. Even I have to try and work out what your examples are, as in your second paragraph.

Comment: Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes, and no. Why mention other languages? The main point to make is: planned/planted. Right?

Comment: Because I perceive the confusion to be arising from interference from a native language

Comment: @Lambie excuse me, can you explain me about why did you say "mixes up tenses" I was curious

Comment: @learnerg5 Yes. Look at this: 'Are "planned" and "plant" pronunciated same way?" That is comparing apples and oranges. You have to compare: plann**ed** and plant**ed**. And no, they are not the same. [the word is pronounced]

Answer (score 0):

Pronunciation in English differs by accent, which generally depends on which region/country the speaker is from, so technically there is no "right way" to pronounce any word in English, not even within the same country.  There are of course standard accents of English, but obviously not everybody speaks in standard accents.  For example, I'm Scottish, live in the UK, and speak Standard Scottish English and my own Scots dialect, but I don't speak what some would consider Standard British English (or RP), which I would actually consider to be an accent of southern England, and certainly not the whole country.

The OED online gives the following for ***plant*** (note that there are two described for British English)

> Brit. /plɑːnt/, /plant/, U.S./plænt/

The adjective/past tense ***planned***

> Brit. /pland/, U.S. /plænd/

Sources: [The OED online](https://www.oed.com/)

For me, /plant/ and /pland/ are the way that I pronounce these.  Also I have never heard any native speaker of English  use the pronunciation /plant/ for planned. It always ends with a distinctive d sound.  To my Scottish ears, the vowel that Americans use for these words sounds a little different from the British versions, but it makes little difference when it comes to understanding Americans. I suspect the same would be true vice-versa.

What I have noticed with Americans is that when there is a *t* at the end of a word which comes before a vowel in the next word, I often hear them use a tapped-d sound to link the two words, whereas here in the UK this is not so common. You are probably more likely to hear a glottal stop used in the UK to replace a final t sound. Again this is just an accent thing and doesn't affect understanding.